# What is the reason my element won't render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Going through Documentation I have attempted to render this searchCard Element Component about 3 different ways I keep getting 'searchCard' is defined but never used or on this last try React.DOM.render I get compile errors.

This is a react app being build in codesandbox

I have tried other render methods and functions. such as

```
 class searchCard extends Component {

 } 

 OR

 const searchCard = () => (); 

 OR

 const searchCard = props => ();
```

This is the searchCard.js File

```
import React from "react";

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import react from "react-dom";
React.DOM.render(
  <div class="card">
    <h5 class="card-header">Featured</h5>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
      <p class="card-text">
        With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.
      </p>
      <a href="/" class="btn btn-primary">
        Go somewhere
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

This is the index.js file

```
`
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import searchCard from "./components/Toolbar/searchCard/searchCard";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Toolbar>
        <TopLinks />
        <SplashScreen />
        <Hpbg />
      </Toolbar>
      <searchCard />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);

`
```

TypeError
Cannot read property 'render' of undefined
evaluate
/src/components/Toolbar/searchCard/searchCard.js:4:10

```
`
  1 | import React from "react";
  2 | import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
  3 | import react from "react-dom";
> 4 | React.DOM.render(
    |          ^
  5 |   <div class="card">
  6 |     <h5 class="card-header">Featured</h5>
  7 |     <div class="card-body">
`
```

evaluate
/src/index.js:8

```
`
   5 | import "./styles.css";
   6 | import Hpbg from "./components/Toolbar/Hpbg/Hpbg";
   7 | import SplashScreen from "./components/Toolbar/SplashScreen/SplashScreen";
>  8 | import searchCard from "./components/Toolbar/searchCard/searchCard";
   9 | 
  10 | function App() {
  11 |   return (
`
```

Comment: Tried and got       _react.default.render is not a function

Comment: Also, does `searchCard.js` export anything?

Comment: Your first 2-3 attempts to define `SearchCard` are correct, you just need an `export default SearchCard` at the bottom of your file. Define `SearchCard` similar to how you defined `App` and export it as default. Also it's common practice to start component name with an Uppercase character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your component like this,

```
import React from 'react';
class SearchCard extends Component {  // Use PascalCase for class name
   render(){
       return(
         <div class="card">
           <h5 class="card-header">Featured</h5>
           <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
            <p class="card-text">
             With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.
            </p>
            <a href="/" class="btn btn-primary">
              Go somewhere
            </a>
           </div>
       </div> 
       )
   }
}
export default SearchCard;
```

In `index.js` file `import` your component like this,

```
import SearchCard from "./components/Toolbar/searchCard/searchCard"; //Try to use PascalCase for component import. Also make sure you are importing from correct path.
```

And finally usage,

```
<SearchCard />
```

Comment: This was the right answer I was just about to answer it this way PascalCase I did use shorter syntax to define the component!  const SearchCard = () => ( ); export default SearchCard; Thanks ya'll for the help